# SVN Ignore Not Applying?

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to figure out svn:ignore.  I am using:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore file://path/myrepository/project
```

Within there I am adding 'files' to that and then saving.  It commits the revision fine.  When I now go to a machine to SVN Update it, it downloads the files directory.  How come that isn't applied?  With SVN, do you need to apply things by doing some sort of restart?  I am using a Red Hat Linux box.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Looks like I misunderstood ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn:ignore` only works for untracked files. once you have added a file to your repository it cannot be ignored again (unless removed again). Why should you ignore a file that you initially wanted to track?

`svn:ignore` only saves you from accidentally adding garbage (build products, backup/swap-files, log files, etc.). It will not forbid downloading of files from the repository (if I understood your last sentence)

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood ignore then.  If I am tracking a folder say var/www/html/myfolder and needed to not track or get var/www/html/myfolder/files in the SVN, can that be removed altogether from SVN without effecting it in that location?

Comment: It can be removed from future history, but not from existing history (at least not without some hackery – don't do it!). To remove it from the repository only, run `svn del --keep-local /path/to/your/file`. Later you can add it to your `svn:ignore` rules, so it won't get committed again